# How to let 3rd party add code to my Grails Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I have developed a Grails (1.3.4) application (Spring MVC, Hibernate). I need to let my customers extend the application but they don't have access to my source code. They have received the WAR file and the DB scripts from me.

My application provides some means to extensibility in the form of recognizing some DB entries that the customers can insert.

The customers want to extend the application further in the following way:

1. They should be able to add gsp and frontend code , that will be invoked when they click on items listed in my application that correspond to the DB entries they inserted.
2. They can do any type of coding in the gsp/frontend code and post methods to backend controller.
3. they should be able to extend the controller to add their own methods to be invoked from their frontend code.
4. As far as I know, when I release next version of my application, I will have to give a new WAR, which will have to replace the existing WAR on the server. Does this mean all his extension work is lost and he needs to re-add them ? how can I preserve his extensions and re-deploy them with the new WAR ?

The customer has his own development environment with Grails and everything else. He has access to the WAR of my application, but not my source code.

I don't have full understanding of all features of Grails/Spring.

Can someone point me to the rights documentation so that I can research myself?

Of course, ready help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
 We moved to Grails 2.1.1 and started using the binary plug-ins. As suggested by Tomas, it worked perfectly for us.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the typical use case for the binary plugin mechanism available in Grails 2. You would need to refactor your code to be a plugin, but this should be fairly trivial.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#binaryPlugins

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Indeed, the plugins are the way to go. But I am stuck with 1.3.4, can't move to 2.X. My questions to you are, 1) with 1.3.4, can my customer create plugins that has its own GSP pages, message bundles, controller methods ? 2) will that seemlessly work with my application ? 3) does he need to re-deploy his plugin every time I release a new version of my application (which destroyes the top folder completely)

Comment: probably the other way around, you provide your application as a plugin and your customer overwrites it in their application. But they will be able to access the source code in pre-1.3.4 version.